# How to keep code running forever in pythonanywhere cloud?

Tags: python, cloud, telegram, chatbot, pythonanywhere

I created a Telegram chat bot and deployed it in pythonanywhere cloud. If I don't use the bot for long hours or a day, then it stops running, and I need to restart it to run the chat bot.
How can I make it run forever on pythonanywhere cloud?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See the pythonanywhere pricing information. Free version does not provide for always running. You need to buy another plan.